# É perigoso deixar mod_mime_magic ativo no Apache?

Tags: apache, arquivo, servidor, upload, mime-type

Uma vez eu estava discutindo com um programador mais experiente que eu (o usuário [@Bacco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/70/bacco)) sobre upload de arquivos.

Eu estava comentando com ele não fazer sentido alguém tentar fazer um upload de um arquivo com extensão `jpg` tendo no conteúdo um script PHP dentro e que não era necessário se preocupar com isso, já que o Apache não iria ler o conteúdo como PHP (pois eu creio que eu tenha visto uma configuração no apache onde é informado as extensões de arquivo que serão interpretadas como PHP).

Contudo, esse usuário informou que isso pode ser arriscado caso a extensão `mod_mime_magic` estiver ativada no Apache, pois teoricamente (para mim é teoricamente pois nunca usei) iria interpretar um arquivo baseado no mime do arquivo e não na extensão.

Até onde vai minha experiência, eu sei que ocorreria problemas ao efetuar um `include` (do PHP) nesse arquivo, aí sim ele seria interpretado como PHP. Mas eu nunca tive problemas com o Apache interpretando um JPG como PHP.

Isso, obviamente, me deixou com algumas preocupações e eu gostaria de saber algumas coisas a respeito:

- Como funciona detalhadamente esse `mod_mime_magic` do Apache?
- Esse `mod_mime_magic` realmente é perigoso assim?
- Ele vem ativo por padrão no Apache?
- Como saber se ele está ativo ou não?
- Se eu quiser ativar o `mod_mime_magic`, como eu poderia garantir que um arquivo que foi "upado" para minha aplicação não tem nenhum "conteúdo malicioso disfarçado"?

Comment: Não vou postar uma resposta completa agora, mas segue um resumo pra quem não pegou a conversa no chat: o módulo Mime-magic usa o arquivo mime-magic do sistema para determinar o tipo de arquivo de acordo com seu conteúdo, em vez da extensão. Isto pode fazer com que um sistema que cheque upload de imagens pela extensão deixe algum usuário subir um PHP "disfarçado" com extensão GIF, por exemplo, que para o Apache, será entendido como PHP por causa do módulo.

Answer (score 2):

Não consigo enxergar uma falha de segurança neste módulo, pois conforme a documentação https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime_magic.html#mimemagicfile o contexto para se usar `MimeMagicFile` é somente configuração do servidor e virtualhost, ou seja apenas alguém com nivel administrativo (ou melhor, com controle completo sobre o servidor) poderia trocar o arquivo magic por algo com problemas, se algo falhar neste contexto, então é um problema que vai muito além dos módulos.

Veja para o "problema" ocorrer, primeiro teriamos que criar um arquivo nomeado `/home/user/meumagic` com este conteúdo (é apenas um exemplo):

```
# php
0  string  \<\?php             application/x-httpd-php

# Frame
0  string  \<MakerFile        application/x-frame
0  string  \<MIFFile          application/x-frame
0  string  \<MakerDictionary  application/x-frame
0  string  \<MakerScreenFon   application/x-frame
0  string  \<MML              application/x-frame
0  string  \<Book             application/x-frame
0  string  \<Maker            application/x-frame

# MS-Word
0  string  \376\067\0\043            application/msword
0  string  \320\317\021\340\241\261  application/msword
0  string  \333\245-\0\0\0           application/msword
```

No apache teria que configurar assim:

```
MimeMagicFile /home/user/meumagic
```

Então neste caso qualquer arquivo que comesse com `<?php` irá executar, todavia veja que é bem trabalhoso, isto é praticamente uma falha de segurança induzida.

### Como um arquivo de upload poderia executar como um script php?

Até aonde entendo dos módulos que conheço do Apache o único que poderia realmente causar uma brecha de segurança seria o `ForceType` do modulo "core", antes de explicar sobre ele vou explicar como funciona a execução dos scripts php no apache (na maior parte das vezes)

O Apache para rodar PHP pode usar vários métodos, todavia os mais comuns são *Fast-CGI* e o *Apache2handler* (este último mais comum em Windows).

Para você definir o que vai executar o php você mesmo irá configurar as extensões de arquivos habilitadas no `httdp.conf` assim (este exemplo seria no windows):

```
LoadModule php5_module c:/php/php5apache2_4.dll
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

Ou:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Ou até (php2, phtml):

```
<FilesMatch "\.ph(p|tml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Então veja que foram adicionados o "mimetype" `application/x-httpd-php` para a extensão .php e .phtml e com isso você poderia usar qualquer extensão, até criar uma assim:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .wallace
```

Todos arquivos terminados em `.wallace` irão rodar scripts PHP.

Agora voltando ao `ForceType`, imagine que de alguma forma o desenvolvedor do script do upload não fez um filtro no upload e isto permite ele subir um arquivo `.htaccess` com este conteúdo:

```
ForceType application/x-httpd-php
```

E em seguida no próximo upload ele enviar um .jpg (neste .jpg) com o seguinte conteudo:

```
<?php
echo 'Oi';
```

E de quebra a pasta de upload tem permissões para execução e acesso publico, então a pessoa mal-intencionada acessaria assim:

```
http://site-vulneravel.com/uploads/upload.jpg
```

Ele iria executar o script.

Note que para a falha de segurança ocorrer foram precisos:

- Permissão na pasta `uploads` para executar o script
- Pasta `uploads` ser publica (ou acessível via http)
- Falta de filtros/validação no script upload

Então você se pergunta, a mas isso é impossível, talvez para quem tenha o minimo de conhecimento e/ou responsabilidade sim, mas vários "desenvolvedores" isso pode acontecer sim.

### Respondendo as perguntas no tópico

- Como funciona detalhadamente esse mod_mime_magic do Apache?

  - Resposta: Ele troca o arquivo magic que contém os mime-types para identificação dos arquivos, .htaccess não tem acesso
- Esse mod_mime_magic realmente é perigoso assim?

  - Resposta: Eu diria que não, se ele vier ser a causa de algum problema de segurança foi por irresponsabilidade de alguém com controle total sobre o apache
- Ele vem ativo por padrão no Apache?

  - Resposta: Varia de servidor para servidor.
- Como saber se ele está ativo ou não?

  - Resposta: Acredito que somente observando o httpd.conf, já que ele é acessível somente neste "nivel"
- Se eu quiser ativar o `mod_mime_magic`, como eu poderia garantir que um arquivo que foi "upado" para minha aplicação não tem nenhum "conteúdo malicioso disfarçado"?

  - Resposta: Conforme expliquei no resto da resposta não acredito que ele poderia causar este problema e se vier a ocorrer não é uma falha diretamente dele e sim de quem controla o servidor.